# While nothing is entered

Tags: python

What do I need to add to force the user to enter something before moving on.

```
print()
print("Question 2")
print("What is the currency of Spain?")
print()
print("A  Euro")
print("B  Dollar")
print("C  Yen")
print("D  Krona")
answer = input("What is your choice: ").upper()

while answer is none #keep asking
if answer == "A":
       print("Correct!")
       score = score + 1
else:
       print("Sorry, the correct answer was A")
```

Comment: `answer=''  while answer=='': answer=input("blah").upper()`

Answer (score -1):

Prompt for input again in a loop:

```
print()
print("Question 2")
print("What is the currency of Spain?")
print()
print("A  Euro")
print("B  Dollar")
print("C  Yen")
print("D  Krona")

answer = input("What is your choice: ").upper()

while answer == "":
    answer = input("What is your choice: ").upper()
if answer == "A":
       print("Correct!")
       score = score + 1
       correct = True
else:
       print("Sorry, the correct answer was A")
```